# pseudo-selector first-of-type doesnt work

Tags: html, css, pseudo-class

So basically I make the .round lose its margin-left property with the first-of-type selector. Funny enough the last-of-type selector works fine.
What am I doing wrong?

```
<div id="box">
    <div id="headline">One big headline</div>
    <div class="round">Button 1</div>
    <div class="round">Button 2</div>
</div>

#headline {
display: block;
width: 90%;
margin-left: 5%;
margin-right: 5%;
top: 50%;
line-height: 1.2em;
font-size: 3.0em;
font-weight: 800;
text-align: center;
text-transform: uppercase;
color: #333;
}
.round {
display: inline-block;
background: #15D43C;
width: auto;
height: 40px;
border-radius: 20px;
padding-left: 2em;
padding-right: 2em;
text-align: center;
font-size: 0.75em;
font-weight: 700;
text-transform: uppercase;
line-height: 40px;
vertical-align: baseline;
color: #fff;
margin-left: 1em;
margin-top: 1em;
}
.round:first-of-type {
    margin-left: 5em;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`:first-of-type` doesn't work how you think it does.

the TYPE of `.round` is `div`. Because the first `.round` isn't the first of it's type (it's the second div within the parent) your selector selects nothing.

`.round:nth-child(2)` would work for this specific example

Answer (score 0):

The `type` is *the element type*, not *thing that matches the result of the selector*.

The first element of the `div` type that is a child of `#box` is not a member of the class `.round`, so nothing matches both `.round` and `:first-of-type`.

Answer (score -1):

JSFiddle here using `:nth-child()`. If possible, I'd prevent using it unless you're intentions are different.

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://fiddle.jshell.net/eR5TC/)**

Here is a good article for you to read on CSS specificity. Instead of targeting if with pseudo selectors, use classes to **modify** that particular element.

PS, you don't need `top: 50%` on your `#heading`, it has no purpose unless positioned fixed, relatively or absolutely.

**[Hacks for dealing with CSS specificity](http://csswizardry.com/2014/07/hacks-for-dealing-with-specificity/)**

Comment: Not sure who down voted, but a reason would of been adequate.